# Can xcode attach and debug python running from a c application?

Tags: python, c, xcode

I'm debugging Blender, which is written in C and integrates python scripts (.py) for extensions. There is no python executable, the blender program calls python directly.  The experience in windows using visual studio 2013 is very simple, I just attach to the process and immediately I can break into the python code even though I have no C code on the machine and have not compiled Blender with any debug info. It all just works, I don't even have to tell it where the .py files are.

When I use XCode,( which I am new to.) I can attach to the process but I have only been able to break into the disassembly on segment faults. I intend to compile the blender source eventually but I'd like to just use naked python code that ships with the product. What else can I do to show Xcode that I need to step into the python code?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is your primary goal, but I'm trying to fire up python from Xcode - so I can develop plugins for Blender.

In general, to have python in Xcode go here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GUBGoeCu19I (short and very informative video on topic).

If it is not enough I've found these two sources: [http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/IDE_Configuration/OSX_CMake_XCode](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev%3aDoc/IDE_Configuration/OSX_CMake_XCode) and some old thread in here: http://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=12044&view=next&sid=76546b4996c3531f00ce1ffea82d8c2d

Hope it hellps :)